# Connecting DB2 Express-C in java using Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, db2

I am pretty new to JDBC and I am trying to write a simple application to connect to a DB2 database residing on the same machine.

I am looking for a code snippet and the necessary steps in order to establish the connection to the database and to send some simple `SELECT` statements to the database.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction in this regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need [DB2 jdbc driver](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/download.html), then you can write something like this :

```
// load the DB2 Driver
Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");

// establish a connection to DB2
Connection db2Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:test","user","pass");

Statement st = db2Conn.createStatement();
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM TEST"; 

// execute the query
ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(myQuery);
```

Comment: Hello !!! I've downloaded the jdbc driver for java, added external jar/zip in eclipse, names are : db2jcc.jar , db2jcc4.jar, sqlj.zip, sqlj4.zip ... now tested the above program and the exception is shown in the Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB@Driver")  , The error is : COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB@Driver which i got through exceptionobject.getMessage()

Comment: What is the exception? are you sure the driver and the license jar are in the classpath? did you install the "Data server client" or where did you get these jars?